# Reentrant lock releases automatically in java

Tags: java, interface, locking

Is there any way can we release the re entrant lock automatically.does not need to unlock in finally block is there any way to achieve this

```
try{
lock.lock;

}
catch(Exception e){

lock.unlock

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with an annotation but using the `AutoCloseable` is also an option:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockTry {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new LockTry().testWithLock();
}

private void testWithLock() {

    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    try (CloseableLock clock = new CloseableLock(lock)) {
        System.out.println("run with lock");
    }
}

static class CloseableLock implements AutoCloseable {

    private final ReentrantLock lock;

    CloseableLock(ReentrantLock lock) {
        super();
        this.lock = lock;
        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("locked");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        lock.unlock();
        System.out.println("unlocked");
    }
}
}
```